# Conditional Expectation of an Exponential Random Variable

Tags: expected-value

I have an Exponential Random Variable X, with rate 1.

How would I go about computing $E[X | X < a]$?

Comment: Write out as integral with respect to density function

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way to do this problem is as follows. By definition of conditional expectation with respect to event we have $\mathbb{E}\left[X|X<a\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E}(X\cdot\mathbb{I}_{\{X<a\}})}{{P}(X<a)}$.
It is easy to verify that the cdf of the r.v. $Y=X\cdot\mathbb{I}_{\{X<a\}}$ is 
$F_Y(t)= \begin{cases}0,\space t\leqslant 0\\ \frac{{P}(X\leqslant t)}{{P}(X<a)}, t\in (0,a]\\1,\space t>a\\\end{cases}$.
From this you can derive the density function $f_Y(t)$  and compute the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[X|X<a\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E}(Y)}{{P}(X<a)}$.